# how to create waves on button with css and html?

Tags: html, css

i'm trying to create a wave lines on button, but i don't have any idea about it.

i want the button like this[image]

Is there way to create a button like this, or any other way to create.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: a wavy image as the background ?

Comment: is there a way to create with css?

Comment: Please provide what you've tried.

Comment: if you're motivated enough to align each and every pixel exactly where you want them and not have any responsiveness then yes, You can apply multiple backgrounds to the button. Or you can create use an SVG which is a more viable solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use some `<svg>`s and `<path>`s and this gonna work.
Here is your code:

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgb(0, 224, 150);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.text {
  width: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1440 320">
    <path fill-opacity="0" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="2" d="M0,192L80,160C160,128,320,64,480,48C640,32,800,64,960,64C1120,64,1280,32,1360,16L1440,0L1440,320L1360,320C1280,320,1120,320,960,320C800,320,640,320,480,320C320,320,160,320,80,320L0,320Z"></path>
    <path fill-opacity="0" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="2" d="M0,160L48,133.3C96,107,192,53,288,74.7C384,96,480,192,576,202.7C672,213,768,139,864,117.3C960,96,1056,128,1152,170.7C1248,213,1344,267,1392,293.3L1440,320L1440,320L1392,320C1344,320,1248,320,1152,320C1056,320,960,320,864,320C768,320,672,320,576,320C480,320,384,320,288,320C192,320,96,320,48,320L0,320Z"></path>
  <path fill-opacity="0" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="2" d="M0,192L60,170.7C120,149,240,107,360,106.7C480,107,600,149,720,176C840,203,960,213,1080,202.7C1200,192,1320,160,1380,144L1440,128L1440,320L1380,320C1320,320,1200,320,1080,320C960,320,840,320,720,320C600,320,480,320,360,320C240,320,120,320,60,320L0,320Z"></path>
    <path fill-opacity="0" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="2" d="M0,192L60,170.7C120,149,240,107,360,117.3C480,128,600,192,720,197.3C840,203,960,149,1080,117.3C1200,85,1320,75,1380,69.3L1440,64L1440,320L1380,320C1320,320,1200,320,1080,320C960,320,840,320,720,320C600,320,480,320,360,320C240,320,120,320,60,320L0,320Z"></path>
    <path fill-opacity="0" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="2" d="M0,0L60,21.3C120,43,240,85,360,112C480,139,600,149,720,133.3C840,117,960,75,1080,90.7C1200,107,1320,181,1380,218.7L1440,256L1440,320L1380,320C1320,320,1200,320,1080,320C960,320,840,320,720,320C600,320,480,320,360,320C240,320,120,320,60,320L0,320Z"></path>
    <path fill-opacity="0" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="2" d="M0,256L60,234.7C120,213,240,171,360,128C480,85,600,43,720,32C840,21,960,43,1080,69.3C1200,96,1320,128,1380,144L1440,160L1440,320L1380,320C1320,320,1200,320,1080,320C960,320,840,320,720,320C600,320,480,320,360,320C240,320,120,320,60,320L0,320Z"></path>
    <path fill-opacity="0" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="2" d="M0,128L60,112C120,96,240,64,360,85.3C480,107,600,181,720,229.3C840,277,960,299,1080,304C1200,309,1320,299,1380,293.3L1440,288L1440,320L1380,320C1320,320,1200,320,1080,320C960,320,840,320,720,320C600,320,480,320,360,320C240,320,120,320,60,320L0,320Z"></path>
    <path fill-opacity="0" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="2" d="M0,64L60,106.7C120,149,240,235,360,234.7C480,235,600,149,720,117.3C840,85,960,107,1080,101.3C1200,96,1320,64,1380,48L1440,32L1440,320L1380,320C1320,320,1200,320,1080,320C960,320,840,320,720,320C600,320,480,320,360,320C240,320,120,320,60,320L0,320Z"></path>
    <path fill-opacity="0" stroke-width="2" stroke="#fff"d="M0,224L40,224C80,224,160,224,240,208C320,192,400,160,480,138.7C560,117,640,107,720,101.3C800,96,880,96,960,128C1040,160,1120,224,1200,261.3C1280,299,1360,309,1400,314.7L1440,320L1440,320L1400,320C1360,320,1280,320,1200,320C1120,320,1040,320,960,320C880,320,800,320,720,320C640,320,560,320,480,320C400,320,320,320,240,320C160,320,80,320,40,320L0,320Z"></path>
  </svg>
  <div class="text">let's try</div>
</div>
```

A living demo: https://codepen.io/marchmello/pen/rNOWWXa?editors=1100